# "vsSwitcher" table class on Wiktionary

Tags: css, mediawiki, wiktionary

I have been looking at implementing Wiktionary's vsSwitcher table class for some time, but cannot find where it is defined. It is used in pages such as the [table generator module used for Finnish declensions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Module:fi-nominals), as well as multiple other such modules and tables. Where can I find a definition or implementation of it? I am assuming it shows up in a .css file somewhere, but I can't track it down.